# Why does python write code from else in if?

Tags: python

I have this python source code:

```
while True:
    answer = input("\nApple or Nokia?")
    if answer == 'Apple':
        print("Nice, you have Apple!")

    if answer == 'Nokia':
        print("Nice, you have Nokia!")

    else:
        print("I do not understand.")
```

But when I run it and write Apple, the python says:

```
Apple or Nokia?Apple
Nice, you have Apple!
I do not understand.

Apple or Nokia?
```

I don't know why python writes "I do not understand."

Comment: `elif answer == 'Nokia':`

Comment: the second `if` should be an `elif` (*else if*). Otherwise on an `'Apple'` input the first `if` and the `else` from the second `if` will be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typo:

```
if answer == 'Nokia':
```

should be

```
elif answer == 'Nokia':
```

your original code is equivalent to

```
while True:
    answer = input("\nApple or Nokia?")
    if answer == 'Apple':
        print("Nice, you have Apple!")
    else:
        pass  # do nothing

    if answer == 'Nokia':
        print("Nice, you have Nokia!")

    else:
        print("I do not understand.")
```